# Adding a label for a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

I have a `JTextField` and I want to add a label next to it, so that it looks like this...

```
        +---------------+
TEAM 1: |Text field here|
        +---------------+
```

This is the code where I am constructing the `JTextField`s...

```
jb = new JButton(">> FIGHT <<");
jt0 = new JTextField("", 25);
jt1 = new JTextField("", 25);
jt2 = new JTextField("<< BATTLE VICTOR >>", 35);
```

Could someone please tell me how to add the label.

Comment: Have you used JLabels yet? You can add a JLabel and put it next to the JTextField. Just make sure your layout fits it correctly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just put a JLabel next to your JTextField.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to add any text to your interface, you should use `JLabel`. By placing a `JLabel` next to a `JTextField`, you can achieve the look you are asking for.

A `JLabel` is simply constructed like this...

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("This is my message");
```

The way you add the `JLabel` to your interface depends on your `JPanel`/`JFrame` layout, but I tend to prefer `BorderLayout`, which you would use like this...

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("Team 1");
JTextField myTextField = new JTextField("Team Awesome!");

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(myLabel,BorderLayout.WEST);
panel.add(myTextField,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This will put a `JLabel` to the left (`WEST`) of the `JTextField`.

Refer to the following documentation for more information:

- JLabel: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html
- BorderLayout: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html

Comment: myTextfield -> myTextField

Answer (score 11):

In addition to [layout selection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), don't forget that "you can improve your program's accessibility by using the `setLabelFor()` method," as discussed in [*How to Use Labels*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html).

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a combination of a layout manager and [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)s

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("User name:");
JTextField field = new JTextField(12);

setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
add(label, gbc);

gbc.grid++;
add(field, gbc);
```

Check out [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more examples